# Switch two column depending to a pattern with pandas

Tags: python, pandas, parsing

I actually have a dataframe such:

```
seq1_id             seq2_id             dN    length1   length2  GC1   GC2   
g13600.t1_0042_0042 g66097.t1_0035_0035 0.10   45         67     0.78  0.67
g1464.t1_0035_0042  g45594.t1_0042_0035 0.67   56         34     0.65  0.87
g34744.t1_0042_0035 g50055.t1_0035_0035 0.08   34         76     0.75  0.45
g12096.t1_0035_0042 g34020.t1_0042_0035 0.43   31         54     0.89  0.76
```

and I would like to change the order of my columns, in fact get on the first column only the gene name with the first _number being _0035 and in the other the first _number being 0042, here it would give:

```
seq1_id             seq2_id             dN     length1   length2  GC1   GC2 
g66097.t1_0035_0035 g13600.t1_0042_0042 0.10    45         67     0.78  0.67
g1464.t1_0035_0042  g45594.t1_0042_0035 0.67    34         56     0.87  0.65
g50055.t1_0035_0035 g34744.t1_0042_0035 0.08    34         76     0.75  0.45
g12096.t1_0035_0042 g34020.t1_0042_0035 0.43    54         31     0.76  0.89
```

as you can se, on the first column, I got only gene name begening with _0035
and when there is a swip, the column length1 and 2 and GC1 and 2 move too.

thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `np.where`, like this:

```
import numpy as np
df.length1, df.legth2 = np.where(df.seq1_id.str.contains('t1_0035'), df.length1, df.legth2), np.where(df.seq1_id.str.contains('t1_0042'), df.length1, df.legth2)
df.seq1_id, df.seq2_id = np.where(df.seq1_id.str.contains('t1_0035'), df.seq1_id, df.seq2_id), np.where(df.seq1_id.str.contains('t1_0042'), df.seq1_id, df.seq2_id)
>>> df
    seq1_id seq2_id dN
0   g66097.t1_0035_0035 g13600.t1_0042_0042 0.10
1   g1464.t1_0035_0042  g45594.t1_0042_0035 0.67
2   g50055.t1_0035_0035 g34744.t1_0042_0035 0.08
3   g12096.t1_0035_0042 g34020.t1_0042_0035 0.43
```

Edit to your followup question:

Comment: Hi, I'm not sur if my post is really clear, In fact I need to get in the column "seq1_id" gene name with their first _number is equal to _0035 and in the column "seq2_id" gene name with their first _number is equal to _0042, in my exemple I had to switch for exemple only the rows 1 and 3. And if you take a look at my desired output, in the first column, all my gene names have in their first_number the _0035 number and the same for the column 2

Comment: @Benjamin Try now?

Comment: Thanks it works, but it actually raises another issue, I also need to switch other column as well, I added it to my first example. Indeed, I have other column corresponding to the length en GC composiiton, and theyrhave to swich as well. Thanks for your help

Comment: @Benjamin I updated the answer, but it's not good form to add additional questions once you got an answer.